# How to generate multiple pdf file PHP Mysql and HTML2PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, html2pdf

I would like to generate multiple PDF files for each sample from my database with html2pdf. I have actually different tables which contain the run name with the idsample. The 12 first character is the run name and the 8 last characters are the idsample, for example:

```
run0112201728S52PRO

run011220178FS22LEJ
```

For all these tables, I want one pdf report for each idsample. I managed to create the pdf but they are all in the same pdf instead of being all in a distinct pdf.
I included the pdf generation part inside the loop.
Any idea how to do it?
Here what I did.

```
<?php

// convert
        //require_once('html2pdf.class.php');
       require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
        
        use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
        use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
        use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

    ob_start();
$tablename='run01122017'; //the name of the table
//GET idsample that we gonna cut from the result_array
$query2 = "select DISTINCT SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,12,8) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'run01122017%'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die ("no query");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $idEcht_array[] = $row2;
    
}
//Query to pick up Idpat
$FetchIdPat="SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM PAT WHERE idEcht='".implode(",",$idEcht_array[$i])."'";

$PerformIdPAT=mysqli_query($conn,$FetchIdPat) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($rowIDPat =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformIdPAT)) { ?>
        Patid:&nbsp;<b><?php echo $rowIDPat["Lastname"]."&nbsp;".$rowIDPat["Firstname"];?>
//}
//Generate PDF report
$content = ob_get_clean();

    

    try
    {
        
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        ob_end_clean();
        //$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'pdf');
$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'.implode(", ", $idEcht_array[$i]).'-Report.pdf');
            
        }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }}
    ?>
```

Comment: Of course all the data will be created in the same pdf -- because  after the output buffering , you create the object Html2Pdf just ONCE and output the $content (also ONCE). If you want the different records to become respective pdf files , then you need to do the pdf generation **separately** --- create object, output $content and save pdf files.  (Hint: put the pdf generation part inside the loop, not outside it)

Comment: @KenLee, thanks for your reply and your clean explanations. I have tried to put the pdf generation inside the loop, but I am getting an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)`

Comment: @KenLee, do you mean, I just need to put inside the loop only this part: `try
    {
        
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
        ob_end_clean();
        $html2pdf->Output($tablename.'pdf');
        
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }`

Comment: I put inside the loop the loop the generation of the pdf and I also tried to make a different table name for each idsample: `$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'.implode(", ", $idEcht_array[$i]).'-NGSReport.pdf');`. But it does not work, I have only one PDF now.

Comment: @KenLee, I updated the code in the post.

Comment: @KenLee, I also changed the name of the pdf output in order to make sure $tablename will be different: `$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'.implode(", ", $idEcht_array[$i]).'-Report.pdf');`

Comment: Please see my answer as a suggested solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the ob_start(); and $content = ob_get_clean(); inside the while loop appropriately, and use say a variable $index to change the filename

So, based on your original code, the revised code is:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
        
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

$tablename='run01122017'; //the name of the table

//GET idsample that we gonna cut from the result_array
$query2 = "select DISTINCT SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,12,8) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'run01122017%'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die ("no query");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $idEcht_array[] = $row2;
}

//Query to pick up Idpat
$FetchIdPat="SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM PAT WHERE idEcht='".implode(",",$idEcht_array[$i])."'";

$PerformIdPAT=mysqli_query($conn,$FetchIdPat) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$index=1;

while($rowIDPat =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformIdPAT)) { 
    ob_start();
?>

Patid:&nbsp;<b><?php echo $rowIDPat["Lastname"]."&nbsp;".$rowIDPat["Firstname"];?>

<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
    
       try
       {
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

        //ob_end_clean();
        //$html2pdf->Output($tablename.'pdf');

        $html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'. $index . '-Report.pdf');
            
        unset($html2pdf); 
            
        }
        catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }

$index++;
}

?>
```

Comment: this is perfect. I really appreciated your help.